# Pass props with React and Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-props

I have all of my firebase functions and variables inside of my Login.js but my Dashboard.js needs to have access to two of those props aswell. For some reason no matter what I try I cannot get it to work. Because I am using gatsby these are two different pages and as well.

This is my Login.js code (where all my functions that I want to pass are)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from "react";
import "../css/Login.css";
import { Link, navigate } from "gatsby";
import BackGround from "../components/bg";
import Navbar from "../components/navbar";
import fire from "../components/fire";

const Login = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState("");
  const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState("");
  const [hasAccount, setHasAccount] = useState(false);

  const clearInputs = () => {
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
  };

  const clearErrors = () => {
    setEmailError("");
    setPasswordError("");
  };

  const handleLogin = () => {
    clearErrors();
    fire
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch((err) => {
        switch (err.code) {
          case "auth/invalid-email":
          case "auth/user-disabled":
          case "auth/user-not-found":
            setEmailError(err.message);
            break;
          case "auth/wrong-password":
            setPasswordError(err.message);
            break;
        }
      });
  };

  const handleSignup = () => {
    clearErrors();
    fire
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch((err) => {
        switch (err.code) {
          case "auth/email-already-in-use":
          case "auth/invalid-email":
            setEmailError(err.message);
            break;
          case "auth/weak-password":
            setPasswordError(err.message);
            break;
        }
      });
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    fire.auth().signOut();
  };

  const authListener = () => {
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        clearInputs();
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser("");
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    authListener();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <BackGround />
      <Navbar />
      {/* {user
        ? (navigate("/dashboard", { replace: true }),
          (<Dashboard handleLogout={handleLogout} user={user} />))
        : null} */}
      {user ? <h1>User</h1> : <h1>No user</h1>}
      <section className="form-signin">
        {hasAccount ? (
          <h2 className="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
        ) : (
          <h2 className="form-signin-heading">Signup</h2>
        )}
        <label className="control-label form-labels">Email</label>
        <input
          className="form-input"
          placeholder="Enter email"
          type="text"
          autoFocus
          required
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <p className="errorMsg">{emailError}</p>
        <label className="control-label form-labels">Password</label>
        <input
          className="form-input"
          placeholder="Enter password"
          type="password"
          required
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <p className="errorMsg">{passwordError}</p>

        {hasAccount ? (
          <>
            <p className="AHAC">
              Not Registered?{" "}
              <span onClick={() => setHasAccount(!hasAccount)} className="AHAC">
                Create an account.
              </span>
            </p>
            <center>
              <button className="form-button" onClick={handleLogin}>
                Login
              </button>
            </center>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <p className="AHAC">
              Already have an account?{" "}
              <span className="AHAC" onClick={() => setHasAccount(!hasAccount)}>
                Sign In.
              </span>
            </p>
            <center>
              <button className="form-button" onClick={handleSignup}>
                Signup
              </button>
            </center>
          </>
        )}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

This is my Dashboard.js (need access to handleLogout function and user variable)

```
import { navigate } from "gatsby";
import React from "react";
import BackGround from "../components/bg";
import Navbar from "../components/navbar";
const Dashboard = ({ handleLogout, user }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <BackGround />
      <Navbar />
      {/* {user ? null : navigate("/Login")} */}
      {user ? <h1>User</h1> : <h1>No user</h1>}

      <h1 className="welcome-text">Welcome, User</h1>
      <h1 className="page-header">You have generated 100 Facts!</h1>
      <center>
        <button className="logout-button" onClick={handleLogout}>
          Logout
        </button>
      </center>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

As always any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a combination of [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Yes, you can use [React Context with Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/2019-01-31-using-react-context-api-with-gatsby/). Take a look at this [useAuth](https://usehooks.com/useAuth/). You could use this as a foundation to build your own custom hook. Something like this:

**Create your custom hook**

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const auth = useProvideAuth();
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={auth}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(authContext);
};

function useProvideAuth() {
  //The auth state and methods you need
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = React.useState("");
  const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = React.useState("");
  const [hasAccount, setHasAccount] = React.useState(false);

  const clearInputs = () => {
    //...
  };

  const clearErrors = () => {
    //...
  };

  const handleLogin = () => {
    //...
  };

  const handleSignup = () => {
    //...
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    //...
  };

  const authListener = () => {
    //...
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    //...
  }, []);

  return {
    user,
    handleLogin,
    handleLogout,
  };
}
```

**Add the provider in the Gatsby Browser file (gatsby-browser.js)**

```
import React from "react"
import { AuthProvider } from "./src/context/AuthContext"
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => (
  <AuthProvider>{element}</AuthProvider>
)
```

**Use it in your components**

```
const Dashboard = ({ handleLogout, user }) => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  // you can access auth.user, auth.logout
  return (
    <div>...</div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't know if i'm doing something wrong (most likely) but this doesn't work for me, It is saying that useAuth() is not defined in my dashboard.js

Comment: You  need to import it similarly to how you import AuthProvider in the gatsby-browser.js file. At the top of your Dashboard file, you need something like
import { useAuth } from "./src/context/AuthContext" // path might be different based on where you have placed this code